# I am new to C++ I am not understanding how to fix the problem please guide where i am making the mistake

Tags: visual-c++

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFdjM.png)

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream.ih'**

Comment: If you look at the same line where the error is displayed, but in the "File" column (on the right), there it shows "Class.h" as the file containing the error. Check that file. (The "Source.cpp" file shown in the screenshot seems OK.) Also, after correcting the errors and compiling, click to switch to and check the "Output" tab (next to the "Error List" tab in the lower left corner of the screen). The "Error List" shows so-called IntelliSense errors, and the "Output" shows the real compiler messages after building.

Answer (score 0):

re write # include <iostream.h>

Answer (score 0):

It should not be the case, I just compiled a basic console project without any errors. DO NOT use iostream.h, depending on the VS version you will get either an error or warning. Do this:

[image: See this screenshot]

This will allow you to see all header files used in the build process in order of dependency. There is another setting you could use but is better to try this.
Are you using other source files in your project/solution?